# Windows Defender

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus

I recently had some malware on my computer and it blocked the Microsoft Defender from running the offline scan ( I tried all of the normal ways to get it started again but they didn't work, so I just reinstalled windows.)

I have seen that there was an option for windows 7  & 8, to run an offline scan from a disk or USB but it did not work for me. Can this be done on windows 10? If yes how?

Also I tried running the scan after booting on safe mode and it said that the IT administrator disabled parts of the app from working.
Is this normal and is there a way to get it to run on safe mode?

Thank You!

Comment: Open Windows Defender and go to the Virus Threat Protection portion. Right side click on Scan Options and select Offline Scan (near the bottom right side). OK , select Scan and let it run.

Comment: I did that but nothing happens. I  think the malware that got on to the computer somehow blocked that is why I wanted to run it from a USB or from safe mode. Thank You! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You are best at this point to back up data and reinstall WIndows.

Comment: There are third-party antimalware antimalware apps (e.g. Kaspersky, Malwarebytes) that can be run from USB or CD, and sometimes they can successfully remove malware... and sometimes, not. The *best* ix is to keep known clean and valid disk images, and restore from them. Second best, which entails a lot of work, is to completely reinstall Windows and reinstall all data and apps.

Comment: https://www.techradar.com/best/best-antivirus-rescue-disk